# node.js parse array from jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm creating an application in node which will get the array sent from jquery Ajax, here is my code:

```
Ember.$.ajax
({
  type:"PUT",
  url:"http://localhost:3000/ids/",
  data:
  {
    ids:[29,12,43],
  },
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

Here is my node.js code:

```
router.put('/ids/', function(req, res) 
{
  var data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.ids);
});
```

The result is:

> { 'ids[]': [ '29', '12', '43' ] } 
>   undefined

I've also tried to iterate over it, but the code:

```
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + data[key]);
  }
}
```

Is not working also. What can I do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The `'ids[]:'` does not look like the correct format for a key in `JSON` - are you sure this is what the console is printing?
In any case, if the data you are receiving is coming in as a string (even when the string looks like `JSON`) - you could try and parse it into `JSON` object. Here is an example for your case:

```
router.put('/ids/', function(req, res) 
{
  var data = req.body;
  //if the string is a properly formatted JSON, this should pass:
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data);
  //then see if this gives you what you expect
  console.log(dataJSON);
  console.log(dataJSON.ids);
});
```

Give it a try and let me know if this helps.

**UPDATE:**
Seeing that the data you receive is not a well-formatted JSON, try changing the PUT request into something like this:

```
Ember.$.ajax
({
  type:"PUT",
  url:"http://localhost:3000/ids/",
  data: JSON.stringify({'ids':[29,12,43]}), 
  dataType: 'json',
});
```

Give it a try and let us know what the console is printing on the server and if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank You for a support, unfortunately yes, this is what console prints, I've tried the code, but the put command crashes, I can't see a reason because it's in the put command. I need to debug it somehow. It looks like it's not correct format which is weird, because the jQuery ajax was working good for me all the time.

Comment: I see, please try and change the data you are sending into a proper JSON-string. I have edited the answer to include this section - try it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I think I found the answer, but I wouldn't make that without Your help, I've wrote a simple parser, it's not really great. I think that's not the best solution, but it works.
`var parsing = data.replace("ids[]","");`
`var parsing2 = parsing.replace(/:/g,'');` <br />
`var parsing3 = parsing2.replace(/"/g,"");`
`var parsing4 = parsing3.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');`
`var parsing5 = parsing4.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');`
`var splitting = parsing5.split(",");` The result the result is an array with numbers

Comment: That's great. JSON parsing is such a common task in Web applications that I really think you should invest sometime to make sure the data being sent is JSON and you won't have to do your own parsing like you did. If this solves your problem, great!